# Time series: Available data graphs (ggplot)

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I discovered the package ***nsRFA*** which I intended to use for precipitation data analysys and I found the function `consistencyplot()` which I think is amazing.

```
> library(nsRFA)
> data(hydroSIMN)
> head(annualflows)
  cod anno dato
1   1 1956 1494
2   1 1957 1309
3   1 1958 1699
4   1 1959 1467
5   1 1960 1918
6   1 1961 1469
> y <- annualflows["anno"][,]
> cod <- annualflows["cod"][,]
> consistencyplot(y,cod)
```

[image]

But I couldn't make it work with other data but the example given in the package example manual (`vignette("nsRFA_ex01", package="nsRFA")`). So I tried to replicate the plot using ggplot but sadly I am lost.

I found it hard to give an meaningful example but using the data from the example above can anyone suggest any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
annualflows %>% ggplot(aes(x = anno, y = cod)) + 
    geom_point(
        shape = 45,
        size = 5,
        col = "blue"
    ) + 
    scale_y_reverse(
        breaks = seq(10, 50, by = 10)
    ) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1920, 1980, by = 10)) +
    labs(
        x = "Year",
        y = "Code"
    ) + 
    theme(
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA),
        text = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "grey80"),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey80")
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Great. If the `annualflows` data frame woud have months, with missing values either (some years not having all the months) how would you proceed? PS. I have a sample of my data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7mw858dxh5MSy1RRldYYnFtY2M/view?usp=sharing), it includes month data.

Comment: You could concatenate the months and years and turn them into a date using something like `df$date <- as.Date(paste(df$ano, df$mes, "1"), "%Y %m %d")` and then use `df$date` as the x value instead of anno, where `df` is the name of your dataframe.

Comment: I tried and got this: `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(x) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis ` any suggestion? Guess I should try `sacle_x_date` but no idea if I'm missing something else.

Comment: I changed the **cod** column from _factor_ to _discrete values_ and now I got the error: `Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator` I also used `scale_x_date`. Any suggestion?